# Java Regex to replace specific character within parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Need help in getting the java regex to replace = sing between parenthesis with #, my input text is

```
8=FIX.4.&49=(550=0449)&35=RIO&76=(AB=4560)&
```

expected output string

```
8=FIX.4.&49=(550#0449)&35=RIO&76=(AB#4560)&
```

So would like to replace = char only within (550=0449) and (AB=4560) with # so the output should contain (550#0449) and (AB#4560).

Comment: is it possible to have orphaned or nested "(" and ")" or will they always have an open and close perenthesis?

Comment: It can be nested but it will be balanced, every opening ( will have closing )  so every = char within ( needs to be replaced even from nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like anubhava's answer, but if you want to be more strict and assert there are non-blank terms and opening and closing brackets, capture the terms and write them back using back references:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\(\\w+)=(\\w+\\))", "$1#$2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("=(?=[^()]*\\))", "#");
```

`(?=[^()]*\))` is a lookahead that will make sure to match `=` only when there is a `)` following it.